# Required request parameter 'idEvent' for method parameter type Integer is present but converted to null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, dto

Im trying to add Users for Events in my project but it throws me that exception

2023-10-31T18:08:19.663+01:00  WARN 15864 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'idEvent' for method parameter type Integer is present but converted to null]

I request good parameters with same names as in entities and dtos

```
addEvent.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Adding User to Event</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Adding User to Event</h1>
<form th:action="@{/addUser}" method="post">
    <label for="idEvent">Choose Event:</label>
    <select id="idEvent" name="idEvent">
        <option th:each="event : ${events}" th:value="${event.idEvent}" th:text="${event.eventName}"></option>
    </select>

    <label for="idUser">Choose User:</label>
    <select id="idUser" name="idUser">
        <option th:each="user : ${users}" th:value="${user.idUser}" th:text="${user.username}"></option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit">Adding User to Event</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
**EventsController**
@Controller
public class EventsController {

    private final EventsService eventsService;
    private final EventsRepository eventsRepository;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public EventsController(EventsService eventsService, EventsRepository eventsRepository, UserRepository userRepository, UserService userService) {
        this.eventsService = eventsService;
        this.eventsRepository = eventsRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/addEvent")
    public String showEventAddingForm(Model model){

        EventsDto events = new EventsDto();
        model.addAttribute("events", events);
        return "addEvent";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addEvent")
    public String addEvent(@ModelAttribute("events") EventsDto eventsDto) {
        eventsService.saveEvent(eventsDto);
        return "events";
    }

    @GetMapping("/addUser")
    public String ShowAddUserForm(Model model) {
        List<UserDto> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        List<EventsDto> events = eventsService.findAllEvents();

        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        model.addAttribute("events", events);
        return "addUser";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public String addUserToEvent(@RequestParam("idEvent") Integer idEvent,
                                 @RequestParam("idUser") Integer idUser) {
        eventsService.addUserToEvent(idEvent, idUser);
        return "addUser";
    }

    @GetMapping("/events")
    public String events(Model model) {
        List<EventsDto> events = eventsService.findAllEvents();
        model.addAttribute("events", events);
        return "events";
    }
}
```

```
**EventsService**

@Service
public class EventsServiceImpl implements EventsService {

    private EventsRepository eventsRepository;
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public EventsServiceImpl(EventsRepository eventsRepository, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.eventsRepository = eventsRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<EventsDto> findAllEvents() {
        List<EventsEntity> events = eventsRepository.findAll();
        return events.stream()
                .map((event) -> mapToEventsDto(event))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public void saveEvent(EventsDto eventsDto) {
        EventsEntity event = new EventsEntity();
        event.setEventName(eventsDto.getEventName());
        eventsRepository.save(event);
    }

    private EventsDto mapToEventsDto(EventsEntity event){
        EventsDto eventsDto = new EventsDto();
        eventsDto.setEventName(event.getEventName());

        return eventsDto;
    }
    @Override
    public EventsEntity findByOwner(UserEntity ownerId) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public EventsEntity findByEventName(@NotEmpty String eventName) {
        return  eventsRepository.findByEventName(eventName);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public EventsDto findById(int id) {
        EventsEntity event = eventsRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Event not found by -- ID :" + id));

        EventsDto eventsDto = new EventsDto();
        eventsDto.setIdEvent(event.getIdEvent());
        eventsDto.setEventName(event.getEventName());
        return eventsDto;
    }

    @Override
    public void addUserToEvent(Integer idEvent, Integer idUser) {
        EventsEntity event = eventsRepository.findById(idEvent).
                orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Event not found by -- ID :" + idEvent));
        UserEntity user = userRepository.findById(idUser).
                orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("User not found by -- ID : " + idUser));
        event.getMembers().add(user);
        eventsRepository.save(event);
    }

}
```

```
**UserService**

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository,
                           RoleRepository roleRepository,
                           PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }
    private RoleEntity checkRoleExist(){
        RoleEntity role = new RoleEntity();
        role.setRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
        return roleRepository.save(role);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveUser(UserDto userDto) {
        UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
        user.setFirstName(userDto.getFirstName());
        user.setUsername(userDto.getUsername());
        // encrypt the password using spring security
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));

        RoleEntity role = roleRepository.findByRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
        if(role == null){
            role = checkRoleExist();
        }
        user.setRoles(Arrays.asList(role));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    private UserDto mapToUserDto(UserEntity user){
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        userDto.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        userDto.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        userDto.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        return userDto;
    }
    public List<UserDto> findAllUsers() {
        List<UserEntity> users = userRepository.findAll();
        return users.stream()
                .map((user) -> mapToUserDto(user))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntity findByUsername(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDto findById(int id) {
        UserEntity user = userRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("User not found by -- ID : " + id));

        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        userDto.setIdUser(user.getIdUser());
        userDto.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        userDto.setUsername(user.getUsername());

        return null;
    }


    public UserEntity getLoggedInUser() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String username = authentication.getName();
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }
```

Why is it converted to null?

Comment: On your form, add the object that you want to bind data to.  `th:object="${events}"`.  On your select, add the field to bind this value to.  `th:field="*{idEvent}"`. You can follow [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) guide to get an understanding of how the data binding works

Comment: But id of the event should be creating already with the event as it is auto incremental in database

Comment: Events are creating properly, but then i cant add users to them

Comment: Ah, yeah, I see this now.  Have you inspected the request that's being made?

Comment: For now I think that I inspected everything, every mapping in Entity is good for sure so I dont know what more I could do as there are no tutorials how to bind two tables by DTO

Comment: You don't need to bind tables, you just need to bind the two fields on your form.  If you inspected your request, what was being sent for idEvent?

Comment: Sorry I think I dont uderstand what are you asking, what request?

Comment: When you're running your application, use Chrome to debug it; use the built-in devtools to view the POST request that's being made.

Comment: Thank you, I saw that and it tells that Required parameter 'idEvent' is not present and addUser:1 
        
       POST http://localhost:8080/addUser 400 (Bad Request) at console